# Possible to compress into a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

```
index = [x for x in range(0,81)]
membership_columns = {
    'column_0': index[0:81:9]
    'column_1': index[1:81:9]
    'column_2': index[2:81:9]
    'column_3': index[3:81:9]
    'column_4': index[4:81:9]
    'column_5': index[5:81:9]
    'column_6': index[6:81:9]
    'column_7': index[7:81:9]
    'column_8': index[8:81:9]
    }
```

Is it possible to squeeze this into a dictionary comprehension? Also, is the list comprehension on line 1 necessary? I wasnt sure how I turn each key into a list comprehension by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely it's possible. I would suggest doing this like so:

```
{('column_%d' % i): index[i:81:9] for i in xrange(9)}
```

Also the first list comprehension is not quite needed as just doing:

```
index = range(0,81)
```

would accomplish the same thing.

You could also replace all of the list slicing with xranges, which are only going to generate your needed values. You could do that like so:

```
{('column_%d' % i): range(i,81, 9) for i in xrange(9)}
```

since the range function in python takes a step parameter. See [the docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

That said, despite this looking more elegant, you do take a performance hit over slicing that will probably get worse with larger comprehensions. At this size it's not really noticeable:

```
import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("{('column_%d' % i): range(i,81, 9) for i in xrange(9)}", number = 100000)
1.3790168762207031
>>> timeit.timeit("index=range(0,81);{('column_%d' % i): index[i:81:9] for i in xrange(9)}", number = 100000)
1.1949927806854248
```

Apparently the string formatting here is slower than I thought. As pointed out by martineau you can get a considerable speed increase using concatenation instead:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("{('column_' + str(i)): range(i,81,9) for i in xrange(9)}", number = 100000)
0.914525032043457
```

However with larger values of `i` it starts to become considerable:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("{('column_%d' % i): range(i,81, 9) for i in xrange(90)}", number = 100000)
12.220430135726929
>>> timeit.timeit("index=range(0,81);{('column_%d' % i): index[i:81:9] for i in xrange(90)}", number = 100000)
9.669343948364258
>>> timeit.timeit("index=range(0,81);{('column_' + str(i)): index[i:81:9] for i in xrange(90)}", number = 100000)
7.163957118988037
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Follow up question: is the index slicing strictly necessary, or is there a list comprehension that would do the same?

Comment: @TravM in fact, you can directly use range for this kind of thing. See updated answer.

Comment: The performance hit over slicing is balanced by not wasting all that space to build an array of indices—and at _very_ large sizes, the comprehension probably starts getting faster again because you also avoid all those cache misses (and, at really big sizes, page misses). But anyway, I think you're right that elegance is probably more important than performance here.

Comment: `timeit.timeit("{('column_' + str(i)): range(i,81,9) for i in xrange(9)}", number = 100000)` seems a little faster.

Comment: @martineau Woah! I had no idea that string formatting was so slow. Updated.